# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal length 0 on DART

Tags: mysql, flutter, asynchronous, dart

when i try to make a simple select with [mysql1 dart library](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1), the app throws this exception:

```
E/flutter (11252): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal length 0
E/flutter (11252): #0      _NativeSocket.read (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:819:7)
E/flutter (11252): #1      _RawSocket.read (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1614:22)
E/flutter (11252): #2      Buffer.readFromSocket (package:mysql1/src/buffer.dart:48:30)
E/flutter (11252): #3      BufferedSocket._readBuffer (package:mysql1/src/buffered_socket.dart:178:36)
E/flutter (11252): #4      BufferedSocket._onData (package:mysql1/src/buffered_socket.dart:93:9)
E/flutter (11252): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (11252): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (11252): #7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (11252): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (11252): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (11252): #10     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:808:19)
E/flutter (11252): #11     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:682:7)
E/flutter (11252): #12     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:624:5)
E/flutter (11252): #13     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1556:33)
E/flutter (11252): #14     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1052:14)
E/flutter (11252): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (11252): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (11252):
```

this is the function that makes the query (I call that function in a FutureBuilder in flutter):

```dart
Future<bool> askPlacaTurno(String idServicio)async{
    var conexion = await conectarse();
    var res = await conexion.query("select placa from servicios where id = ?", [idServicio]);
    bool usaPlaca = false;
    for(var row in res){
      usaPlaca = row[0] == 'on' ? true : false;
    }
    return usaPlaca;
  }
```

***EDITED***

the connection and close connection functions, here is the problem, i've tried to make a connection without execute any query and throws the same exception:

```dart
Future conectarse() async{
    final conexion = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
        host: "192.168.0.18",
        port: 3306,
        user: "root",
        password: '',
        db: "gobernacion"
      )
    );
    print("conectado a la base de datos");
    return conexion;
  }

  Future desconectarse(MySqlConnection conexion) async{
    await conexion.close();
  }
```

[image: table services]

Comment: Does your table `servicios`  has a column call `placa` and the `id` in your table is not duplicated any place?

Comment: @Sisir that table has column 'placa' and the id is unique, i allready edited the question with an image of the table